# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create (undefined method `find_by')

Tags: ruby

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_to user
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

By using above code, I am unable to sign in with my details. Hope, some one will help me out of this....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're rolling your own authentication, or using the likes of Devise?

Comment: A reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Answer (score 2):

Change your first line in `create` method to:

```
@user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
```

The reason you get this error is that you probably use Rails 4 `find_by` method in Rails 3 application.